# Fn:GetAtt Not returning StateMachine.Name as string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

In my Serverless yaml I'm attempting to trap the full StateMachine name in a custom var:

```
STATEMACHINE_ARN_NAME: 
  Fn::GetAtt: ["preMobilizatonStateMachine", "Name"]
```

The statemachine is defined as...

stepFunctions:
     stateMachines:
       preMobilizatonStateMachine:

According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-stepfunctions-statemachine.html

```
{ "Fn::GetAtt": ["MyStateMachine", "Name"] }
```

should return a string value of: MyStateMachine-ABCDEFGHIJ1K

But when I attempt to deploy I get the following error:

*Trying to populate non string value into a string for variable ${self:custom.STATEMACHINE_ARN_NAME}. Please make sure the value of the property is a string.*

Comment: Where is the custom variable STATEMACHINE_ARN_NAME declared in the cloudformation?  Can you share the cloudformation snippet?

Comment: I'm hitting the same problem; I think the evaluation of the function happens after trying to use it, so you're seeing the object instead of the evaluated string. Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, turns out the root cause was because I was using an optional like so: ${opt:variableName, '${self:custom.someVariable'}
Where custom.someVariable was using the GetAtt function.

Apparently optional variables do not work with the GetAtt function, as soon as I removed the optional part everything started working.

environment:
  SOME_VARIABLE:
    Fn::GetAtt: [RedisCluster, RedisEndpoint.Port]